# Unable to an apk in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, build, apk

Title: Trouble Generating APK for React Native Project

Description:
I'm encountering difficulties while trying to generate an APK for my React Native project. Here's the rundown of the steps I've taken:

Bundling JavaScript Code: I've used the react-native bundle command to bundle my JavaScript code into a single file (index.android.bundle). The command seems to execute without errors, and I can see the generated bundle file in the specified directory.

bash
Copy code

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Building APK: After bundling the JavaScript code, I navigate to the android directory of my React Native project and run the Gradle assemble task to build the APK.

bash
Copy code

```
cd android
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

However, when I check the build directory, I can't find the generated APK file.

Could someone please help me troubleshoot this issue? Am I missing any steps or making any mistakes in the process? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you execute the gravel command you get a lot if text output including the errors that causes the build to fail. I would start with this output.

Comment: Make sure to go in the right output directory: `androd/app/build/outputs/apk/<build_variant>/<name>.apk`. Check for any errors that can appear during the `assembleRelease`. Remember also that in order to generate a valid release version, you need valid keys to sign your app. If you want just to generate a valid apk to give "to your friends" you should make another build type without the need of release configuration (since debug one will try to connect always to Metro Server).